# Testing if gradle task executed

Tags: gradle

I am working with the axion gradle plugin and my goal is to test if the **createRelease** task has been executed. If so, I would like to edit a variable that my project depends on. How can I test if a gradle task has been successfully executed. I tried the **onlyIf** predicate and testing if it is **not null** but, the latter only tests if the task exists rather than if it was run.

I would like to run this test in the **ext** closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a listener that is notified on task events, e.g. with `gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { if (it == createRelease) { /* do stuff */ } }`. But you should not change Gradle configuration in that listener. You should only change configuration in configuration phase. That listener of course is run during execution phase.

You should change your strategy in that case, e.g. by doing `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { if (it.hasTask(createRelease)) { /* do stuff */ } }`. The `whenReady` is done during configuration phase, so you can still configure tasks and so on. So with that line you do stuff if the `createRelease` task will be run as part of the current Gradle execution.

Comment: thanks for the help. should I run this in the ext closure?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you run it. the `ext` closure just enables you to add new properties to the object where you apply it. This has nothing to do with that code, as it just registers a listener.

Comment: Don't believe this answer is correct. At least currently in Gradle 6.2 you can't check for the existence of a task with a `whenReady` closure. If you ask for a task to be executed on the command-line and that task doesn't exist the build fails after config phase but before the `whenReady` closure is called.

Comment: Maybe you read the question wrongly. Besides many things have changed in Gradle since 2017, the answer should still be vaild. In OP's case the task always exists, the point was to test whether the task will get executed during the current Gradle run. It was not about intercepting calling a non-existing task from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Every Gradle task provides a [`TaskState`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskState.html) that provides the information you require:

```
task a { }

task b {
    onlyIf { a.state.executed }
}
```

You may also use `a.state.didWork` (or `a.didWork`), if you want to check whether the task really did something (e.g. a `Copy` task).

**Edit:**
I just noticed, that you mentioned to use this functionality in a plugin. One example for this use case:

```
project.gradle.buildFinished {
    if (project.tasks['myTask'].state.executed) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but, shouldn't b.state.executed be a.state.executed?

Comment: great. If a executed and I want to do, let's say a print statement, it would go where?

Comment: I would like to run this in the ext closure. Will the example still work?

Comment: I don't know why it should not work. However, I also don't know why you should need to run it in the `ext` closure. Also, this exceeds the scope of this question, you can simply try it out on your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156122/discussion-between-lu-koerfer-and-crt).

Comment: For those who are reading this in 2023, this suggestion breaks the Gradle configuration cache.